# cross-platform distribution for command-line tools

Tags: node.js, software-distribution

I've built a small commandline tool in node.js and bundled into binaries for windows and mac ( bundled using pkg: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

now that the binaries exist and can be distributed, I'm looking for ways to get them installed, and have their path added to any appropriate PATH variables in an automated way for a user who is a relative layperson.

any suggestions would be very much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to create a binary for doing this. You publish your node module as a npm package and use `npm link` to bind it into the operating system.

If want to use the complied version (incase you want to protect your code from decomposition), even that is possible with that by that method. Just build a node module with your binary included.

[Here](https://medium.com/netscape/a-guide-to-create-a-nodejs-command-line-package-c2166ad0452e) is a good article that describe how to do so.

Comment: I'm familiar with npm, however I don't want my users to need git/npm installed,  which is why I built binaries